# Measure Theory - Absolute Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A question from my homework:

> Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on the real line w.r.t to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $\mu(\{x\})=0 $. is $\mu$ necessarily absolutely continuous w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure?

We say $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. to $m$ if for every measurable set $E$ such that $m(E)=0$ than $\mu(E)=0$ also.

I can't see a reason why this should be true, but can't find a good counter example. I tired some variations on the counting measure. Also tried to construct some measures that give positive measure on uncountable sets and zero measure on countable, be these come out non-additive (i.e. not measures).

Would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there are non-atomic measures whose support is a set of measure zero.

These are called singular continuous measures and they are not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

For example, the measure corresponding to the [devil staircase function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) has as it's support the Cantor set, but the measure of every point is zero.

Let $F$ be the devil staircase function on the unit interval. Then we can define a Borel measure on the unit interval which is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure and has no atoms as follows: for $E\subset[0,1]$ set

$$\mu_*(E)=\inf\sum_{j=1}^\infty F(b_j)-F(a_j)\tag{1}$$

where the infimum goes over all coverings of $E$ with intervals $(a_j,b_j)$, $j=1,2,\dots$.

This is the Riemann-Stieltjes outer measure associated to $F$. Go ahead and prove that it really is an outer measure. Then we apply Caratheodory's extension theorem (as in the construction of the Lebesgue measure) to obtain a corresponding Borel measure $\mu$ (such that $\mu_*(E)=\mu(E)$ for measurable $E$).

Note that $\mu((a,b))=F(b)-F(a)$. Since $F$ is continuous, it really follows that $\mu(\{x\})=F(x)-F(x)=0$. On the other hand, the measure is not absolutely continuous, because $\mu(E)=\mu(C\cap E)$ for every measurable $E$, where $C$ is the Cantor set. Since $\lambda(C)=0$ ($\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure) we see that $\mu$ is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Since you wanted a measure on the real line just extend this measure on the unit interval by $0$ outside of $[0,1]$.

This construction works with any increasing function and it provides (after proper normalization) a 1:1 correspondence  between increasing function and positive Borel measures (see Stein, Shakarchi *Real Analysis*).

*Note:*

Every positive Borel measure $\mu$ (say on the unit interval, it also works on $\mathbb{R}$ but there you need $\sigma$-finiteness as additional assumption) can be uniquely decomposed as

$$\mu=\mu_a+\mu_{sc}+\mu_{pp}$$

where $\mu_a$ is absolutely continuous, $\mu_{sc}$ is a singular continuous measure (i.e. singular and no atoms) and $\mu_{pp}$ is a pure point measure, i.e. the support consists entirely of atoms (all with respect to Lebesgue measure, but also other measures can be used).

Look up the Radon-Nikodym theorem in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* for a reference.

Comment: Should it read $\mu(E) = \mu(C \cap E)$ instead of $\mu(C) = \mu(C \cap E)$?

Comment: @gerw: Yes, certainly! Edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No. Every Borel measure which does not contain Dirac measures (non-atomic) and is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure has this property.

For example the uniform probability measure on the Cantor set which is defined as follows.
Let $C$ be the Cantor set which is defined as $C=\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$, where $I_n$ is a union of $2^n$ disjoint closed interval, each of length $3^{-n}$. Then define the functional
$$
\ell_n(f)=\frac{3^n}{2^n}\int_{I_n}f\,dx, \quad f\in C[0,1].
$$
Clearly, $|\ell_n(f)|\le \|f\|_{\infty}$. It is not hard to show that $\{\ell_n\}$ converges weakly in ${\mathcal M}[0,1]$, and its limit $\ell$ is realized by a positive Borel measure $\nu$, i.e.,
$$
\ell(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\nu,
$$
which has the required properties.